# Spring MVC UrlBasedViewResolver custom view file

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have a view resolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

And a Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadPage(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session,ModelMap modelMap ) {
 String langlayout = "eng";
            UrlBasedViewResolver urlResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();          
            urlResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/"+langlayout);
            urlResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return "home/list.jsp";
}
```

after clicking in the jsp its still looking in the **WEB-INF/views/home/list** instead of **WEB-INF/views/eng/home/list** 
How can I define custom view page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution for my question

```
<!-- Declare a view resolver -->
     <bean class="com.project.controller.AppPortalViewResolver">
        <property name="viewResolver" ref="viewResolver" />
    </bean>
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

**AppPortalViewResolver.class**

```
public class AppPortalViewResolver implements ViewResolver {

 private ViewResolver viewResolver;

 public void setViewResolver(ViewResolver viewResolver) {
  this.viewResolver = viewResolver;
 }


 @Override
 public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
      /* do your logic to change the view name  */
      viewName = "ur_folder_structure";
     return viewResolver.resolveViewName(viewName, locale);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadPage(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session,ModelMap modelMap ) {
 String langlayout = "eng";
            return langlayout+"/home/list.jsp";
}
```

Comment: Yes i tried this..but i have do this in one time configuration ? like chaining view resolver